# table row insertion is not working as expected in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am adding 'tr' additionally to the table body, but, it is adding row wrongly as below:

```
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
<td>
<input class="code" type="text" value=" ">
</td>
<td>
```

but, it should be

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input class="code" type="text" value=" ">
    </td>
    <td></tr>
```

JQuery

```
var elemTabe = tab=$("div#documentation table#refdoc tbody");



    var cols="";

                for (var i = 0; i < tabColLen; i++)
                {
                    cols += '<td><input type="text" class="code"   value=" "  /> </td>';
                }       

                $(elemTabe).append('<tr></tr>').append(cols);
```

where i went wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $tr = $('<tr>')
for (var i = 0; i < tabColLen; i++)
{
      $tr.append($('<td>').text('<input type="text" class="code"   value=" "  />'));              
}  
$(elemTabe).append($tr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .wrapAll():

```
var elemTabe = $("div#documentation table#refdoc tbody");
var cols="";
for (var i = 0; i < tabColLen; i++)
{
   cols += '<td><input type="text" class="code"   value=" "  /> </td>';
}       

$(elemTabe).append(cols).children().wrapAll("<tr/>");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hxyyesng/)

Answer (score 0):

You excatly wrote in this line of code:

```
 $(elemTabe).append('<tr></tr>').append(cols);
```

to put `<tr></tr>` before your cols variable.

change it to:

```
 $(elemTabe).append('<tr>').append(cols).append('</tr>');
```